# Is there a short way in Python to check if an object is list-like (i.e. a `Sequence` but not a `str`)?

Tags: python, types

The shortest (readable) form I've got is:

```py
isinstance(obj, collections.abc.Sequence) and not isinstance(obj, str)
```

I was looking through the [docs for collections.abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) and was surprised to find that there isn't already a unique type to represent that.

Then I learned that [`isinstance` accepts a tuple of types to check against](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), but sadly, it doesn't also accept a tuple of exceptions.

Finally, I learned about the [`Union type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-union), which has a nice syntax sugar where you can just bitwise-or types together, like so for instance: `int | float`. So naturally, I tried doing `collections.abc.Sequence & ~str`, which didn't work.

Comment: What’s your use-case for this and how does the code you posted not satisfy it? This is a fairly esoteric requirement, which is why there’s no predefined type/method for this. This lack shouldn’t particularly surprise anybody.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't know, guess it doesn't feel esoteric to me. The use-case if for checking two objects made out of nested dicts and lists against each other, one representing a pattern to follow, the other being tested. Well, there, `str`s, `int`s and `float`s are the sort of leaf values to test against each other, whereas `dict`s and `list`s (and other types) provide the structure.

Comment: The split could have been on immutables (for leaf values) and mutables (for the structure), but sadly there are also `tuple`s for the structure.

Comment: OK but in this case why would you test for sequence-likeness instead explicitly for `list` or `dict`? In fact, I’d probably have a function `is_leaf_type` and hard-code the supported leaf types (or use an equivalent solution with subtypes and/or pattern matching). Testing against generic sequence-y types doesn’t lead to descriptive code — it only *coincidentally* matches your structure (and not even that, as you noticed). … in other words, and to quote PEP-20: explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yeah you may be making a good point here, food for thought. Thanks

Comment: I don't think your function needs to be so general as to allow arbitrary iterables. Your data structure seems to be made of dicts and lists, with everything else a leaf.

Comment: All the mutable sequences implement the .pop() method, right? Maybe you can check for that instead

Comment: @chepner well, if only... it can actually be pretty much any kind of Sequence or Mapping. On the "values" side it's more well defined. But this is not really the point, it's just an example, I would like to focus on the general case here, to see if there actually exists a concept of structure vs value, or something like that.

Comment: @PabloHenkowski There actually is `collections.abc.Mutable` that can be helpful for that. However, `tuple`s are immutable (just like `str`s), but in this context they look more like a structure to hold values in, rather than a value themselves (at least this is the case in our business logic).

Comment: By the way, regarding the structure vs value paradigm I see there, it may help to know that these nested objects are built from `yaml` files (in most cases, in my use-case). So this seeing `str`s as values and `list`s/`tuple`s as structures might be a convention coming from the `yaml` format. I'll have to dig into that.

Answer (score 0):

A characteristic of the `str` type is that it is a sequence, but *immutable*. So most types which you want to cover are *mutable* sequences.

There is the [`MutableSequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSequence) abstract base class which represents this behavior.

Comment: `MutableSequence` excludes tuples as well as strings, though.

Comment: @chepner Yes, and that's an issue. 

Is it really that arbitrary to view strs (along with ints, floats, etc) as unique values; and lists, tuples, dicts, etc as kinds of structures ?

Comment: Yes. I think you are overgeneralizing: will the data structure you want to traverse really be made of *arbitrary* sequences, including generator expressions, `map` and `filter` objects, etc? Or is it sufficient to consider lists/dicts versus anything else?